# Can Windows Server 2022 read passed through SAS drives in a JBOD configuration?

Tags: sas, lsi, windows-server-2022, diskpart

I recently bought a simple RAID controller card (LSI-9210-8i), and flashed it to IT mode. I also bought a single SAS drive of 3TB. I formatted the drive in the LSI Card's BIOS, and have checked the drive in MEGARAID, and it is reading as "Unconfigured (Good)". I am able to see the drive once I boot into Windows Server 2022, but upon trying to clean the disk with DISKPART or the disk utility, I get an I/O error: "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.", with error event ID 153 (retry I/O operation) being the only thing that appears in event viewer.

Sorry for the incredibly long setup and background, but I am new to using SAS drives, and I was wondering if Server 2022 is unable to read SAS drives passed through in JBOD, and if the disk would need to be set up in a RAID configuration before Windows could use it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about SAS drives. If the controller is supported, they'll appear in Windows like any other drive.

Comment: Thank you; I didn't think that there was, but the repeated failure to do anything on the OS level with that drive, while being able to use the SATA drives through the card made me think there may have been some difference I was unaware of. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tyler Just check, as I'am unsure for LSI, but the disk in the LSI controller should be set to JBOD's mode, as else the LSI controller can't know what are your goal with that disk. I would check that if you can't do nothing with the disk in the OS level.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I just checked, and it is set to JBOD. I even swapped out the SAS drive with a SATA one in the same configuration, and the SATA drive showed up and is useable in Windows with no problem. So from here, I think I'm just left to believe that I got incredibly unlucky and got a dead or defective disk.

Comment: Sounds like a bad drive.